# How to enable Google Drive access for selective set of users

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

How to enable Google Drive access for selective set of users, so that they can use the Drive software on their machines to organize data. Rest of the users should just have web access alone.

Comment: How do you control own-machine software intalls for those users for any other tool? Won't the same tool apply to Drive's software?

Comment: Would it be possible to restrict Google Drive access to selective set of users via the Google Apps console.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Drive doesn't yet have the Org. Unit level controls that many of the other Google Apps services do (like Gmail and Calendar), but one option to consider is in Drive > General Settings where you can select "Allow use of Google Drive for Mac/PC, but hide the download links in the Drive interface". You could then distribute the download link to your select users, and at least the rest of your users would never be prompted by Google to download the Drive client.